# Data pushed in a json object erases when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am storing a data in a json object. The data is then displayed in a table. But when I refresh the page, all the data is lost. How can I retain the data in the object once it is pushed in the object.

product.json file is an empty json object because I need data to be pushed in it.

```
<Button
                          color="success"
                          type="button"
                          className="waves-effect waves-light me-1"
                          onClick={() => {
                            products.push({
                              eventID: products.length + 1,
                              title: this.state.title,
                              startDate: this.state.startDate,
                              endDate: this.state.endDate,
                              time: this.state.time,
                              address: this.state.address,
                              link: this.state.URL,
                              details: this.state.details,
                              uploadedImage: "Image not available",
                            });
                            console.log(products);
                            this.setState({ addNew: false });
                          }}
                        >
```

Pushing the data in this way. How can I keep the data stored?

Comment: If page is refreshed, the data is flushed. You'd be left to re-process it on the server side and give it back to the client or have the client potentially retain some of this data in their localstorage dedicated to your site. This however is not always an option.

Comment: So you may want to be looking in the direction of hosting some type of Database and utilizing that to the best of your practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store added data somewhere, like server or local storage depends on type of data etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can write JSON into local storage and just use JSON.stringify (non-jQuery) to serialize a JavaScript object. You cannot write to any file using JavaScript alone. Just cookies or local (or session) storage.

```
const products = [
    {
        name: 'Dhayalan',
        score: 100
    }
];

localStorage.setItem('productsStorage', JSON.stringify(products));
```

And to retrieve the object later, such as on page refresh or browser close/open...

```
const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productsStorage'));
```

We might do something like this also -

```
<script>
    let products = [];
    function storeData(data){
        products = retriveData();
        products.push(data)
        localStorage.setItem('productsStorage', JSON.stringify(storedData));
    }

    function retriveData(){
        try{
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productsStorage'));
        } catch(e) {
            return [];
        }
    }
</script>

<Button
    color="success"
    type="button"
    className="waves-effect waves-light me-1"
    onClick={() => {
    this.storeData({
        eventID: products.length + 1,
        title: this.state.title,
        startDate: this.state.startDate,
        endDate: this.state.endDate,
        time: this.state.time,
        address: this.state.address,
        link: this.state.URL,
        details: this.state.details,
        uploadedImage: "Image not available",
    })
    console.log(products);
    this.setState({ addNew: false });
    }}
>
```